# Replace parameters in a text file

Tags: java

I have alot of text files with the folling structure: `FileName_Location.txt`.
Within the textfile there are three values, which i have to replace.

```
<filename="" location="" extension="">
```

So it would be     `<filename="FileName" location="Location" extension="txt">`

I get all those values by the filename. But it could also be possible that the values/parameters in the textfile are wrong, so I have to overwrite them.

**My problem is how I can exact locate the right positions to add or replace the values.**

Comment: Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Java code making heavy use of regular expressions which works on a single line from your original question.  It extracts out several groups and then rebuilds the line, inserting the values you want along the way.

```
String pattern = "^(<filename=)(\".*\")\\s(location=)(\".*\")\\s(extension=)(\".*\">)$";
String input = "<filename=\"\" location=\"\" extension=\"\">";
// you can uncomment this next line to test the case when values be
// already present in the input line
//String input = "<filename=\"stuff\" location=\"stuff\" extension=\"stuff\">";
System.out.println("Input string:");
System.out.println(input);

// you can replace these next 3 variables with whatever values you want
// e.g. you could put this code into a loop
String fileName = "FileName";           // a new filename
String location = "Location";           // a new location
String extension = "txt";               // a new extension
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    res.append(m.group(1)).append("\"").append(fileName).append("\" ");
    res.append(m.group(3)).append("\"").append(location).append("\" ");
    res.append(m.group(5)).append("\"").append(extension).append("\">");
    System.out.println("Output string:");
    System.out.println(res);
} else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

This code has been tested on IntelliJ version 11 (yes I'm too lazy to upgrade) and it works fine.

**Output:**

```
Input string:
<filename="" location="" extension="">
Output string:
<filename="FileName" location="Location" extension="txt">
```

Comment: Test out the regular expression in Regex 101.  You will see how it works.  I break up your input string into pieces and then reassemble it with the values you want, replacing if necessary.

Comment: Helped me, but could you explain which purpose have \\s ? marks a space?

Comment: Correct.  `\\s` is a single whitespace character (e.g. a space).  You have spaces between the filename, location, and extension pieces of the string.

Comment: Happy to help.  You _might_ have been able to pull this off using `String.indexOf()`, but regex is much safer and cleaner IMO.

Comment: Hey I have noticed that this works only when "" is empty, but I have also some cases where its already filled...did you considered that?

Comment: No, it works when _anything_ is in the original string.  Try it out and you will see.  Remember, I _replace_ what I match for the filename, location, and extension values with the new values you want.

Comment: The input variable contains the text content?  Or im wrong?

Comment: I don't understand this question.  My code will work whether or not there is contents in between the quotes, so as long as the quotes appear.

Comment: I mean, I actually read from a textfile. I save the whole content into a string. This string (input) I have to match with pattern?

Comment: ".*?(<filename=)(\".*\")\\s(location=)(\".*\")\\s(extension=)(\".*\">).*?";  this solved my problem.

Comment: Good to know.  It sounds like your actual data is a bit different than what is specified in the OP then.